# How to push values in existing array on firestore in nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this token schema over the firestore contains id and array of tokens

{
userId: "some String",
"tokens": [
"token1", "token2"
]
}

I need to push new tokens in tokens array where an Id matches with this schema userId

I am using this below code but not able to push values

```
    docRef.get().then(async function (doc) {
        if (!doc.empty) {
           let here1 = await db.collection("tokens").doc(doc.id);
            let here = doc.docs.update({
            deviceTokens: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(body.deviceToken)
            })

        }})
```

can someone explain what's the error here?

Comment: If you are looking to add data in your code I would like to direct you to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data). As it provides several ways of writing data to Firestore. 
For questions or concerns pertaining to Firebase implementation, please follow the [Firebase Support page](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0). Since they would be better suited in providing answers to your Firebase inquiries.